# how to detect all symbol on mathematical operators on php using regex?

Tags: php, regex, string, operators

how to detect all symbol on mathematical operators on php using regex?

example :

```
$operators = [">0",">=1","==12","<9","<=1","!=4"];
$results = array();
foreach ($operators as $key => $value){
  detect $value using regex, if include symbol of maths operators {
    array_push($results, $value);
    // just push $value with format of symbol of maths operators, example : ">" // remove 0 on my string
  }
}
```

from my array i want to collect just math operators, my expected results:

```
$results = [">",">=","==","<","<=","!="];
```

how to do that?
thank you advanced

Comment: just use `array_map` and `preg_replace` function..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `array_map` along with `preg_replace` like as

```
$operators = [">0", ">=1", "==12", "<9", "<=1", "!=4"];
print_r(array_map(function($v) {
            return preg_replace('/[^\D]/', '', $v);
        }, $operators));
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => >
    [1] => >=
    [2] => ==
    [3] => <
    [4] => <=
    [5] => !=
)
```

[**Demo**](https://3v4l.org/ECN3R)